# Node-RED: Couln't access selected drop down value in js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node-red

Not able to get a selected drop-down value, in the **ValidateInput** function

The below code is to validate user input entered in the text box and provide a response based on the data type selected in the drop-down.

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="input.js">
    RED.nodes.registerType("myNode", {
        category: "function",
        color: "#a6bbcf",
        defaults: {
            data: {
                value: ""
            }
        },
        inputs: 1,
        outputs: 1,
        icon: "file.png",
        label: function() {
            return this.data || "myNode";
        },
        oneditprepare: function() {
            $("#selectMe").on("click", function() {
                    var selectedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
                    console.log("selectedVal:", selectedVal)
                    if (selectedVal == "photograph") {
                        $("#select-text").hide();
                        $("#select-photograph").show();
                    } else if (selectedVal == "geolocation" || selectedVal == "text" || selectedVal == "number" || selectedVal == "decimal" || selectedVal == "sensor") {
                        // this.data = "MYDATA";
                        $("#select-photograph").hide();
                        $("#select-text").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#select-text").hide();
                        $("#select-photograph").hide();
                    }
                })
             },
    });
</script>
<script type="text/html" data-template-name="myNode">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-select-data"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Choose Input type that you want:</label>
        <select id="selectMe">            
    <option value="">Select Data Type</option>
    <option value="text">String</option>
    <option value="number">Integer</option>
    <option value="decimal">Decimal</option>
    <option value="sensor">Sensor</option>
    <option value="geolocation">Geo Location</option>
    <option value="photograph">Photograph</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="select-text" hidden>
        <label for="node-input-data"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Enter the Data to be validated:</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-input-data" placeholder="Data..">
    </div>
    <div id="select-photograph" hidden>
        <label for="node-input-data">Select a Photograph file:</label>
        <input type="file" id="node-input-data" name="myfile">
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html " data-help-name="myNode ">
    <p>A simple node that validates the Data respect to the data type entered</p>
</script>
```

JS:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    "use strict ";

    function ValidateInput(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
        this.log("RED:", RED);
        this.data = config.data;
        console.log("config:", config);
        console.log("data:", data);
        var node = this;
        node.on("select", function(msg, send, done) {
            var inputEntered = node.data;
        });
        node.on("input", function(msg, send, done) {
            var inputEntered = node.data;
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
            var decimal = /^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/;
            if (inputEntered.match(letters)) {
                msg = {
                    payload: "Your input have been accepted",
                };
            } else if (inputEntered.match(numbers)) {
                msg = {
                    payload: "Your input have been accepted",
                };
            } else if (inputEntered.match(decimal)) {
                msg = {
                    payload: "Your input have been accepted",
                };
            } else {
                msg = {
                    payload: "Your input is wrong for this field",
                };
            }
            node.send(msg);
        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("myNode", ValidateInput);
};
```

Comment: You also still have 2 `input`'s with the same id, this will not work

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of the general concepts of Node-RED nodes.

The HTML file (and included scripts) run in the browser and is used at configuration time.

The JS file runs entirely in the backend runtime and has no direct access to anything from the HTML file not passed as part of the `config` for the node.

If you want to validate the config input, then you will need to add javascript code to the HTML file in the `oneditsave` handler not the JS file.

The `node.on('input',...)` function is called when a new message is delivered from the previously wired node, it is not used to process config information.

I suggest you read the [doc](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/first-node) about how to write Node-RED nodes.